# Git,ssh,Cygwin and folders outside of Cygdrive install folders

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

I am having terrible time getting files that reside on C:/ drive on remote computer. I can clone projects if they are under Cygwin installation folder. But I cannot get anything going with my real projects if they reside in something like "/cygdrive/c/myproject/git/export"?

So I cannot get anything from the line below

"ssh://user@remote/cygdrive/c/myproject/git/export"

But this works (for test)

"ssh://user@remote/myproject/export"

I would really appreciate some help. I wasted quite a bit of time on this.
Both computers use Cygwin+SSH+Git successfully inside out except trying to pull, clone projects from non Cygwin default folders

Comment: have you tried using msysGit instead?

Answer (score 1):

First of all(this way useful when you will connect to remote cygwin often) 
 you can create unix-like mapping either by regedit (see key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Cygnus Solutions\Cygwin\mounts v2) or by utility 
`mount [<win32path> <posixpath>]`

Use cygpath.exe to discover path by windows path specification.

At least you can always use notation with direct win path framed by quotes "c:\myproject"

Also it is possible that you have problems with permission, that is why ssh doesn't allow you get content of `/cygdrive/c`